# Efficient way of copying between std::complex vector and Intel IPP complex array

Tags: signal-processing, memcpy, intel-ipp

I'm using Intel IPP for signal processing.The top-level function are using std::vectorstd::complex > data types whereas the Intel IPP equivalent is Ipp32fc[]. The Ipp32fc data type is defined as

```
typedef struct {
Ipp32f re;
Ipp32f im;
} Ipp32fc;
```

From what I know, the Ipp32f data type is simply a C/C++ float. So far, I have been using for loop for copying, and it squeezes the processor a lot, considering the symbol rate I'm processing. I have tried to use standard memcpy without much luck.

All suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function named  ippsCopy_32f which copies the content from one vector to other vector. Maybe you can try using the function for copying and see if it helps. Please refer to the below link which helps you to get more details regarding the respective functions which are present under the Vector Initialization Functions section in the IPP developer reference guide.
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/ipp-dev-reference/top/volume-1-signal-and-data-processing/vector-initialization-functions/vector-initialization-functions-1/copy.html